# How to divide each element of an array by a particular number in gnuplot (pm3d)?

Tags: plot, gnuplot

There is a data file `data.dat` which contains:

```
1   1   1   2   2   6   1
2   4   1   4   1   7   1
3   1   1   6   1   6   1
4   1   1   8   9   76  1
5   1   1   16  1   1   1
6   6   1   9   1   2   1
7   1   1   7   1   99  1
8   8   1   5   8   1   1
9   1   1   3   1   0   1
10  1   1   2   1   1   1
```

I am plotting a color plot using pm3d map in gnuplot. I want to normalize the plot by dividing each value by the maximum value of the array. I use :

```
set pm3d map
stats "data.dat" matrix
splot for[i=1:10] 'data.dat' matrix using ($i/STATS_max)
```

It shows error at `$i` as :

```
Column number expected
```

Is there a way to tell `gnuplot` that I need to access each element of the matrix and apply some operation (division here) on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is in referencing the column with `$i`, one can use the function `column` for this, i.e., `using (column(i)/STATS_max)`